# jQuery on dragstart event scroll wheel is not working

Tags: jquery

Scroll wheel stop working when dragging an item to the target element using jQuery on dragstart event.

How can I enable the scrollwheel without using plugins like jQuery UI?

```js
(function($) {
  $("ul li", document).on('dragstart', function(event) {
    console.log("dragstart")
  });

  $("#content", document).on('dragenter', function(event) {
    console.log("dragenter ");
  })
})(jQuery);
```

```css
ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li draggable="true">item 1</li>
  <li draggable="true">item 2</li>
  <li draggable="true">item 3</li>
  <li draggable="true">item 4</li>
</ul>
<div id="content" scroll="true" style="background: green;height: 150px; overflow:auto;">
  <div style="background: pink;height: 150px;"></div>
  <div style="background: orange;height: 150px;"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you looking to specifically disable the scrollwheel, or *any* form of triggering the `scroll` event?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I want to enable the scrollwhell when dragging an item to #content element.